# Show messagebox if data is not according to format

Tags: excel, vba, validation, messagebox

I've got a pivot table and in that pivot table there's one column that needs a validation check.
If in this column there's no email adres than I need to show a messagebox.
So there needs to be a check on the format.
Data validation is not possible in a pivot table.
Anyone can help me with this one?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this construction:

```
our_range = Range("A1:A100") '  your range or user-defined selection
For each cell in our_range:
    if isempty(cell) then msgbox "Cell "+cstr(cell.address)+" is empty!"
    if instr(cell.value, "@") = 0 then msgbox "Cell "+cstr(cell.address)+" isn't an e-mail!"
next cell
```